# Only some of my Facebook Pages can join a Group?

Tags: facebook

I am only able to join a Facebook group with 1 of the 5 pages I run? How do you join with anyone of my pages not just the 1 Facebook is showing me?

Comment: I have a similar Problem: I can not join a group with my page where I'm already a member of with my private account (that is also the admin of the page).

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?